# ProcessingTimeExecutor:66 - Current batch is falling behind. The trigger interval is xxx milliseconds, but spent xxx milliseconds

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I've playing with streaming data with Apache Spark. I've wanted to test the `Trigger` feature based on the provided [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#overview) in Spark Site.

I've trying to calculate the average of the value in last 4 seconds.
This is my code:

```
# thumbling window of size 4 seconds
parsed = opc \
.groupBy(
    window(opc.sourceTimeStamp, "4 seconds"),
    opc.id
) \
.agg({"value": "avg"}) \
.withColumnRenamed("avg(value)", "avg")\
.orderBy("avg", ascending=True)
```

And then write this dataframe to the console setting the trigger value to 2 seconds.

```
query = parsed \
.writeStream \
.format("console")\
.outputMode("complete")\
.trigger(processingTime='2 seconds') \
.start()
```

In the console, I've get the error messages:

`WARN  ProcessingTimeExecutor:66 - Current batch is falling behind. The trigger interval is 2000 milliseconds, but spent 5157 milliseconds`.

Can you tell me what does it mean? Why it didn't trigger it 2 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question is covered in spark doc itself in trigger section.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#triggers

Trigger timing depends on the type of trigger you specified. For trigger with unspecified type, next trigger will start as soon as previous trigger's work completed. Your micro-batch work took 5157 ms to complete hence next trigger's work didn't started after 2 seconds.
Check the trigger type table written in the doc.

Comment: Well, you're right about the docs. But it doesn't make sense this way of work. I've trying to manipulate the micro-batch with fixed interval and the way that Spark support is using Trigger. My aim is simple trigger it 2 second. But it says, `If the previous micro-batch takes longer than the interval to complete , then the next micro-batch will start as soon as the previous one completes.` So, that doesn't make sense for me. I've tryinh to manipulate the micro-batches time but it says `micro-batch couldn't start at the specified period`. How can i prevent it if the trigger doesn't do it?